# How do i fetch the list of date folders in ADLS and pass them to delete activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a ADF pipeline with only one activity and that  is delete activity

Below is my ADLS folders , here raw is container name

```
 /raw/2022-05-28/omega/omega3.txt
 /raw/2022-05-28/demo/demo3.txt

/raw/2022-05-29/omega/omega2.txt
/raw/2022-05-29/demo/demo2.txt

/raw/2022-05-30/omega/omega1.txt
/raw/2022-05-30/demo/demo1.txt
```

My intention is to delete all the folders inside the raw container expect the current date folder

The folders to be deleted are below .

```
2022-05-28
2022-05-29
```

So basically once the pipeline get completed only the below folders and files needs to available because they belong to current date

```
/raw/2022-05-30/omega/omega1.txt
/raw/2022-05-30/demo/demo1.txt
```

Right now This is what doing

1. Created  a dataset for ADLS and gave the container name and 2022-05-28 in folder
2. Created a pipeline with delete activity  and with #1 dataset
3. Running the pipeline two times manually by altering the dataset folder for 2022-05-28 and 2022-05-29

I dont want to have manual intervention like this , I want to pass array of folder dates to passed automatically based on number of old folders in ADLS , so How do i fetch the list of folders in ADLS and how to extract the date folder of that list and pass that list of folder dates as array to my delete pipeline

Can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not ideal to change the name to delete each folder manually, you can use **Dynamic parameters.** We can use `Get Metadata` activity to get the folder names, `For Each` activity to loop through each folder name, `If conditional` activity to compare the folder name to current date folder, and finally `Delete` activity to delete the folders.

- Create a dataset pointing to your container that holds all these folders (raw). Create a parameter folder_name for this dataset and give its value as `@dataset().folder_name`

[image]

- Use `Get Metadata` activity referring to the dataset just created with field list as `child items`. Give '/' as the value for parameter `folder_name` (We do not need dynamic parameter value in this activity).

[image]

- Create a for each activity. The output of get metadata activity is passed to this for each activity. In For Each -> Settings, give the items field value as `@activity(‘get_foldername’).output.childItems` where get_foldername is the name of the get metadata activity.

[image]

- Under For Each -> Activities, create an activity for this activity. Using `If conditional` activity, under activities tab, build an expression,
  `@not(equals(utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd'), item().Name))` (if current date folder name is not equal to the for each activity folder_name). When this condition is true, we need to perform delete activity (create delete activity for true case).

[image]

- In `Delete` activity, use the dataset created initially, and give the value for `folder_name` as `@item().Name` (dynamic parameter).

[image]

Publish and run the pipeline. It will run successfully and delete all the other folders except the folder with current date. This way you can delete the folders from your container which do not belong to the current date.

Comment: I am trying this approach , It helps

Comment: It worked , but I have one question here, we are using the same dataset (source_dataset_to_delete) in 2 activities  such as metadata activity and delete activity, while using that dataset in metadata activity why / is given so when that metadataactivity runs, it will looks for child items inside /raw// or /raw/ or both same?

Comment: Hey @SurenderRaja, we have created a parameter for dataset called `folder_name`. In Get Metadata activity, while using this dataset, we must give a value for this folder_name parameter (It cannot be blank). Since the dataset needs to point to `/raw/`, we need to give a value to folder_name such that it does not affect the path to container. If we give any value other than `/`, it is considered as a folder inside the raw container (/raw/<folder_name>) which will not be present in the container and the pipeline does not work as intended.

Comment: Using `/` in metadata is helping us to read both `/raw//` and `/raw/` as same (path to container).